# BigQuery SQL query to Indicate a sequence of 3 rows sharing the same value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need a query that every time the indicator column turns into zero and there are 3 zeros in a row, I would like to assign them a unique group number.

Here is a sample data:

```
select  0 as offset, 1 as indicator, -1 as grp union all
select  1,  1,  -1  union all
select  2,  1,  -1   union all
select  3,  1,  -1  union all   
select  4,  1,  -1   union all  
select  5,  1,  -1   union all  
select  6,  1,  -1   union all  
select  7,  0,   1   union all  
select  8,  0,   1   union all  
select  9,  0,   1   union all  
select 10,  1,  -1   union all  
select 11,  0,   2   union all  
select 12,  0,   2   union all  
select 13,  0,   2   union all  
select 14,  1,  -1   union all  
select 15,  1,  -1   union all  
select 16,  1,  -1
```

In this example there are two sequences of 3 zeros, indicated as grp=1 and grp=2.

Comment: what will happen if there are 4 or more zeros in a row - ignore? so only assign new group when it is 3 in a row?

Comment: This correct, only 3 zeros in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select offset, indicator, if(grp = 0, -1, grp) as grp
from (
  select offset, indicator, dense_rank() over(order by pregroup) - 1 as grp
  from (
    select offset, indicator, 
      if(countif(indicator = 0) over(partition by pregroup) = 3 and indicator = 0, pregroup, -1) as pregroup
    from (
      select offset, indicator, count(*) over win - countif(indicator = 0) over win as pregroup
      from your_table
      window win as (order by offset)
    )
  )
)
```

if applied to slightly modified sample data n your question (with sequence of 4 zeros - just for test purpose) - output is

[image]

Comment: appreciate make me notice the logic error in my previous answer.  Reading your query is enjoyable and helpful to me as always.

Comment: @Mikhail this is cleaver and creative approach.

Answer (score 1):

The below query solves this.

Firstly it assigns all of the desired groups a tag.

Secondly, we get the row number for them and use integer casting on row_number to assign them a unique group number.

```
with data as (select  0 as offset, 1 as indicator, -1 as grp union all
select  1,  1,  -1  union all
select  2,  1,  -1   union all
select  3,  1,  -1  union all   
select  4,  1,  -1   union all  
select  5,  1,  -1   union all  
select  6,  1,  -1   union all  
select  7,  0,   1   union all  
select  8,  0,   1   union all  
select  9,  0,   1   union all  
select 10,  1,  -1   union all  
select 11,  0,   2   union all  
select 12,  0,   2   union all  
select 13,  0,   2   union all  
select 14,  1,  -1   union all  
select 15,  1,  -1   union all  
select 16,  1,  -1 ),

tagged as (select 
*,
-- mark as part of the group if both indicators in front, both indicators behind, or one indicator in front and behind are 0.
case 
when indicator = 0 and lead(indicator) over(order by offset) = 0 and lead(indicator, 2) over(order by offset) = 0 then true
when indicator = 0 and lead(indicator) over(order by offset) = 0 and lag(indicator) over(order by offset) = 0 then true
when indicator = 0 and lag(indicator) over(order by offset) = 0 and lag(indicator, 2) over(order by offset) = 0 then true
else false
end as part_of_group
from data),

group_tags as (
select
*,
-- use cast as int to acquire the group number from the row number
CAST((row_number() over(order by offset) + 1)/3 AS INT) as group_tag
from 
tagged
where
part_of_group = true)

-- rejoin this data back together
select 
d.*,
gt.group_tag
from data as d
left join
group_tags as gt
on
d.offset = gt.offset
```

Comment: Interesting approach, need to take a second look.

Comment: On second thoughts, this approach will not work if there are groups greater than 3 as suggested in a comment on the original question. Adding an additional check for ones on either side would fix this issue, however.

Comment: It is a special case of 3 in a row, so non generic approach will work.

Comment: Ah ok, I have edited the question as I realize now using `mod` would not work, but there appears to be a solution using `cast`.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider below approach as well,

```sql
WITH partitions AS (
  SELECT *, indicator = 0 AND COUNT(div) OVER (PARTITION BY div, indicator) = 3 AS flag
    FROM (
      SELECT *, SUM(indicator) OVER (ORDER BY offset) AS div FROM sample_data
    )
)
SELECT offset, indicator, IF(flag, DENSE_RANK() OVER w, -1) AS grp
  FROM partitions
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN flag THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ORDER BY div)
 ORDER BY offset;
```

**Query results**

[image]